# Is the strange problem I'm having to do with comparing floats?

Tags: interrupt, data-type, float

I have a timer interrupt that controls a stepper motor, on an UNO board. In the interrupt handler it checks the speed of the motor and compares it to the target speed. This allows the motor to accelerate to the target speed in a non-blocking way.

This is the relevant part of the interrupt handler:

```cpp
ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect){
    if (targetSpeed > 0 || motorSpeed > 0){
        // leading edge of the step cycle
        if (leadingEdge){
            digitalWrite(STEP_PIN, HIGH);
            stepNumber++;
            // check speed and adjust if necesary
            if (motorSpeed < targetSpeed){
                motorSpeed += speedIncrement;
            }
            else if (motorSpeed > targetSpeed){
                motorSpeed -= speedIncrement;
            }

            leadingEdge = false;
        }
        // trailing edge
        else{
            digitalWrite(STEP_PIN, LOW);
            leadingEdge = true;
        }
    }
    OCR1A = minInteruptsPerStep + (minInteruptsPerStep * (1 - motorSpeed));
}
```

In the `loop()` I have a function that checks the state of `motorSpeed` to control other functions

```cpp
if (motorSpeed == targetSpeed) {
    motorState = RUNNING;
} else if (motorSpeed < targetSpeed) {
    motorState  = ACCELERATING;
} else if (motorSpeed > targetSpeed) {
    motorState  = DECELERATING;
}
```

`motorSpeed` and `targetSpeed` are floats and range from 0-1, in steps of 0.1 `speedIncrement` is 0.001 As far I can see that should ramp the speed up until `motorSpeed == targetSpeed`, in 100 steps. And this mostly what happens. The speed gets to `targetSpeed` and motorState switches from `ACCELERATING` to `RUNNING`, as expected.. mostly. The problem is that it occasionally starts flipping between the three states, for no reason I can see--there is nothing that should modify the value of `motorSpeed` outside the interrupt handler, so once it stops accelerating it should be stable.

Is this because I'm using and comparing floats? Should I scale the speed variables up and use an int or even a byte?

Comment: is motorSpeed  declared volatile?

Comment: Yep, all the variables in the interrupt handler are volatiles

Comment: There is a library for that: https://www.airspayce.com/mikem/arduino/AccelStepper/

Comment: I tried that, but had some problems with it and the LCD library I'm using, the two wouldn't co-exist for some reason.

Comment: They do not use the same timer, it should work. Perhaps they use too much memory. Which LCD library is it and is that working now?

Comment: it's liquidCrystal, I did some initial testing using another library for menus and the accelStepper. But then I ended up developing my own menu class, and learning about both interrupts and C++ classes, so I'm happy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The biggest problem here is that floats don't compare well.  The issue is that a float isn't an exact number. It is, to a large extent, an approximation.

Some numbers cannot be represented by floats, so your "100" may be actually "100.00001", or "99.999999".

It is better to use integers whenever possible. Do your calculations using larger numbers, and then scale down the results when you need to use them.

If you're working in steps of 0.1 between 0 and 100, you should really be working instead in steps of 1 between 0 and 1000, and then divide by 10 later on when you need to use the value (if you even really need to do that).

Here's a little example I knocked up on Linux:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
    float f = 0;
    while (f < 100) {
        f += 0.1;
    }
    printf("%.6f\n",f);
}
```

You'd expect it to give "100.000000" as the answer. It doesn't. Instead you end up with 100.099045. That's because the closest it gets to 100 is actually the previous iteration: 99.999046.

If you do want to compare floats the best way is to use a "within X" operation.  Here's a little macro:

```
#define WITHIN(A,B,DIFF) (fabs((A) - (B)) <= (DIFF))
```

Then you can:

```
if (WITHIN(motorSpeed, targetSpeed, 0.1)) { 
    ...
}
```

That should give you TRUE if the motorSpeed and targetSpeed are within 0.1 of each other.

Comment: Thanks. I haven't done much low level programming before, so I wasn't aware of the float issue. I might try changing to a more appropriate data type.

Answer (score 3):

You already know, from previous answers, why the comparison doesn't give
you the result you expect: you assumed that any multiple of 0.1 is also
a multiple of 0.001, which is true for real numbers but nor for floats.

To fix the issue, it has been suggested to you to allow for some
fussiness in the comparison. I would suggest a different approach: keep
your comparisons as they are, and instead change the way the speed is
updated in the ISR:

```c++
if (motorSpeed < targetSpeed) {
    motorSpeed = min(motorSpeed + speedIncrement, targetSpeed);
}
else if (motorSpeed > targetSpeed) {
    motorSpeed = max(motorSpeed - speedIncrement, targetSpeed);
}
```

With this logic, `motorSpeed` will always end up being *exactly* equal
to `targetSpeed`, irrespective of whether the speed change is a multiple
of the increment or not.

A common misconception about floating point numbers has it that they are
not exact. Truth is, most floating point calculations involve rounding
errors, but the floating point numbers themselves are *exact numbers*,
if not the numbers you expect¹. Then, when you do the assignment

```c++
motorSpeed = targetSpeed;
```

which the code above ends up doing at some point, you can test

```c++
if (motorSpeed == targetSpeed) ...
```

and it will be true.

¹ When you write “0.1” in the source code, you get the `float` which is
closest to 0.1, which happens to be 0.100000001490116119384765625
*exactly*.

Comment: Nice idea, but it still elaves the problem of the comparison in the main loop() which checks the motor state. I've been reading about floats and I undertand the problem better, but what still puzzles me is that it doesn't seem to be deterministic. Since the value of motorSpeed and the value of targetSpeed is constant once the motor reaches a stable state—and in my tests it does report that `motorSpeed == targetSpeed`, why then after reporting this as true for hundreds of steps does it suddenly switch to false, even though there's nothing in the code that changes the value of either variable?.

Comment: Note that motorSpeed is *not* a measurement, it's the speed the arduino is telling the motor to run at, so it's not a mechanical issue.

Comment: I used this technique with ints, which solved the problem of speedIncrement not necessarily being a multiple of targetSpeed, and also the main loop() problem

Comment: @stib: Computations with floats _are_ deterministic. If you witness non deterministic behavior, you will have to search somewhere else in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You should never compare two floats with == or != directly. The reason is that floats are not accurate, so maybe 1.0 can be 0.99999999999, and the other value 1.0 might be 1.00000000001 (simplification).

Instead, use a 'range', like:

```
if (fabs(motorSpeed - targetSpeed) < 0.001)
{
   // Equal
}
```

This means the difference should be smaller than 0.001. fabs means the absolute value of a float (mathematic symbol |x| for the absolute value).

If you make more compares this way, make 0.001 a #define or const.